# How to add https trusted certificate to AWS instance

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, https, ssl-certificate

I have made an app with Spring Boot on backend and UI in AngularJS. UI is separate from the backend. UI is deployed in Firebase and my backend in deployed in AWS (via boxfuse). I want to add a trusted https certificate to my backend but Certificate Manager does not let me create a trusted certificate for Amazon owned domain. How can I add a certificate to the backend (with Let's Encrypt)? Does my UI also need a trusted certificate?

Comment: If you say "UI" does it mean "Frontend"? This both things are different technical aspects.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you are using public domain of EC2 instance, I would advice not to use because whenever you start and stop instance, It will change the domain. If you are doing with let's encrypt than you should do it in the server which having apache configured. Let's encrypt provide you the ACME client, most recommended is certbot. Choose your OS and Web server. It will provide you the script, Run that script in your server and it will ask for required detail which needed to get SSL Certification. Rest of the things script will do it for you. Please read the documentation before you perform this things.

You should consider the domain type as well either you are using single domain or wildcard according to your application.

Below link is useful for me, If you want you can get more detail about this.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority